# MacOS terminal issues

Tags: zsh, macos, homebrew

I tried installing hombrew for mac os and faced some issues while adding to path, now terminal welcomes me with this messages, how can I fix it?

```
.zprofile:export:4: not valid in this context: export HOMEBREW_PREFIX
.zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context: Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
```

.zprofile :

```
# Added by Toolbox App
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/randus/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

.zshrc :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/randus/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208607/4667 -- see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bzsh%5D+not+valid+in+this+context

Comment: Please add the contents of `.zprofile` and `.zshrc` to your question.

Comment: This may not be what you want to hear, but FWIW my ***opinion*** - after using both `homebrew` and `MacPorts` for several years - is this: `MacPorts` is a far better choice for a macos package manager than `homebrew`. But don't take my word for it - research this yourself.

Comment: FWIW, Those are the errors you'd get if `~/.zprofile` contained: `export 'export HOMEBREW_PREFIX'` and `~/.zshrc` contained `export Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts`

Comment: @glennjackman, newer versions of zsh treat `export` as dual keyword/builtins like ksh does. So `export var=$(cmd)` no longer subjects the command substitution to word splitting. `not valid in this context: export HOMEBREW_PREFIX` is evidence that the space between `export` and `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` didn't trigger splitting.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can find SH_WORD_SPLIT on by default in Zsh’s Git log as back as the first commit in 1999. So, I don’t think it’s quite accurate to say “newer versions of zsh”. ;)

Comment: @MarlonRichert, not sure what you mean, shwordsplit is about splitting *parameter expansions* and has never been on by default except in sh/ksh emulation. zsh has always done IFS-splitting on *command substitutions* in list context. The change I'm refering to is [this one](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/39b28980f38e83e15cdeb19a489b5659af97fe93) which makes it that `export var=$(cmd)` is no longer a list context as `var=$(cmd)` is interpreted as assignment

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Put space between `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/randus/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"` and `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

Steps:

- `nano /Users/randus/.zprofile`
- Add space after scripts", so finally your `zprofile` contents should look like `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/randus/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts" eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`
- Control + O
- Enter
- Control + X
- Restart terminal

Comment: Or `path+=( ~/'Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts')` for a more zsh-y way to add a directory to `$PATH`.